# React Native: Access to Clipboard History

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, events, clipboarddata

Android has a keyboard feature that allows a user to view their Clipboard History, up to one hour.

Is there a way to access this Clipboard History in React Native?  The React Native Clipboard API has `getString` and `setString`, which only handle the most recent item copied.  I believe `getStrings` just accesses the clipboard if it's an array, but I don't think it accesses the history (and it's iPhone only anyway).

Alternatively, I *could* theoretically have an event listener on the clipboard functionality, where it just listens for a Copy event and saves it to memory to be accessed later.  I couldn't find a Copy event to listen to, and if I went that route I'd need the app to be open during startup (I think it's possible, but I haven't done it before).

Anyone have any ideas?